# Prolog statement syntax

Tags: prolog

`member(K,[a,b,c,d])` if for one of ...

What's the statement for two of ...?

Comment: You are going to have to clarify this question a bit.

Comment: See my comment under this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939054/how-to-solve-this-problem-by-prolog/1941239#1941239

Answer (score 2):

Just rinse and repeat:

```
?- List = [a,b,c,d],member(X,List),member(Y,List).
```

If you want two distinct elements then,

```
?- List = [a,b,c,d],member(X,List),member(Y,List),X \== Y.
```

Then wrap it up in a predicate if that's what you're after:

```
two_members(X,Y,List) :-
    member(X,List),
    member(Y,List),
    X \== Y.
```

Comment: By using `dif/2` for expressing term inequality you could preserve [tag:logical-purity] even when working with non-ground terms.

Answer (score 1):

I have interpreted the intended semantics of predicate `two_members/3` somewhat differently:

- We want to *draw* items `X` and `Y` from the given list `Ls`.
- `Ls` must have at least two list items for `two_members/3` to succeed.
- `X` and `Y` may be equal if `Ls` contains `X` at least twice.

Based on the builtin predicates `select/3` and `member/2` we define:

```
two_members(X,Y,Ls) :-
   select(X,Ls,Ls0),
   member(Y,Ls0).
```

Let's run some queries! First, the query the OP suggested in the question:

```
?- two_members(X,Y,[a,b,c,d]).
X = a, Y = b ;
X = a, Y = c ;
X = a, Y = d ;
X = b, Y = a ;
X = b, Y = c ;
X = b, Y = d ;
X = c, Y = a ;
X = c, Y = b ;
X = c, Y = d ;
X = d, Y = a ;
X = d, Y = b ;
X = d, Y = c ;
false.
```

What if some item occurs more than once in `Ls`?

```
?- two_members(X,Y,[a,a,b]).
X = a, Y = a ;
X = a, Y = b ;
X = a, Y = a ;                % redundant answer
X = a, Y = b ;                % redundant answer
X = b, Y = a ;
X = b, Y = a ;                % redundant answer
false.
```

What about above redundant answers? Where do they come from and can we avoid them?

The redundant answers come from `select/3` and `member/3`:

```
?- select(X,[a,a,b],Xs).
X = a, Xs = [a,b] ;
X = a, Xs = [a,b] ;           % redundant answer
X = b, Xs = [a,a] ;
false.

?- member(X,[a,a,b]).
X = a ;
X = a ;                       % redundant answer
X = b.
```

To get rid of these redundancies, we can use 
[`memberd/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29433121/4609915) instead of `member/2` and 
[`selectd/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30207770/4609915) instead of `select/3`. Let's run above queries again:

```
?- selectd(X,[a,a,b],Xs).
X = a, Xs = [a,b] ;
X = b, Xs = [a,a] ;
false.

?- memberd(X,[a,a,b]).
X = a ;
X = b ;
false.
```

The redundant answers are gone! So let's re-define `two_members/3` accordingly:

```
two_members(X,Y,Ls) :-
    selectd(X,Ls,Ls0),
    memberd(Y,Ls0).
```

Here's above query of `two_members/3` that *used to* give these redundant answers:

```
?- two_members(X,Y,[a,a,b]).
X = a, Y = a ;
X = a, Y = b ;
X = b, Y = a ;
false.                        % all of above redundant answers have gone!
```