# How to solve this logical description with Prolog?

Tags: prolog, linear-programming, logic-programming

That's my first question so please be tolerant.

I've logical problem to write in prolog/CLP:

> "It is known only one character is
>   telling the truth.
>  Mr April says
>   Mr May tells lies.
>  Mr May says Mr
>   June tells lies.
>  Mr June says
>   that both Mr April and Mr May tell
>   lies.
>  Write a program which
>   determines who is telling the truth."

I solve problem on the paper and the solution is that Mr May tells truth.

But how write it in prolog? I maybe found similar resolution: [WHO KILL - Similar solution](http://www.2shared.com/file/pbNg3y0n/1_6_kto_zabil.html)

but I don't understand that. May someone know how do this or have another example?

Please help if you could :):):)

Comment: Check out the answers to question [1939054](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939054/how-to-solve-this-problem-by-prolog).